# how to extract each line into different variable with bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, awk

i want to extract all words with the all spaces and characters from each line which is located after word "test" into array and then select these part by number.

*text.txt*

```
aa
test `test one`
bb
test `test two`
test `test three`
cc
```

*script.sh*

```
 awk -F'test' '{print $2}' text.txt
```

*this is the result:*

```
test `test one`

test `test two`
test `test three`
```

what i want is to select each line by number, for example i want to use

```
test two
```

as string in some part of my shell script. and i want to get this as number ex:

```
echo "second sentence: ${WORDS[1]}"
```

do you have an idea who to do this? thanks

Comment: This is an odd and quite possibly wrong thing to want. What problem are you actually hoping to solve?

Comment: i want to get all words after particular character "test" in text and then excess it with number

Comment: You are repeating your requirement rather than clarifying it. *Why* do you want to be able to do that?

Comment: actually i want to extract all words after my particular word and then put it into array and finally just call from array. to get my result

Comment: Yes yes yes. **Why?** If you have a concrete problem which you are attempting to solve, explain it so we can understand the end goal, and perhaps suggest a different and better approach. See also [XY Problem.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: i have a automation test script which need to know which test i want to execute, that's why i need a exact description of each test, i have a list of tests with their descriptions in front of each word and this word is "test", is it clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166142/discussion-between-jack-and-tripleee).

Comment: I'm afraid I can't join chat right now, I can check back in an hour or two. If you can show at least in pseudocode how the overall logic is supposed to work, that would help us understand and evaluate your approach.

Comment: Nothing so far suggests that you really neede to access things in a different or random order, and so processing the tests sequentially without storing anything anywhere would seem like a superior solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution:

```
awk '$1 == "test" { $1 = ""; gsub(/^[ \t]/,"",$0); gsub("`","",$0); printf "declare WORDS[%d]=\"%s\"\n",cnt,$0; cnt+=1 }' text.txt > tmp.sh && . tmp.sh && rm tmp.sh
```

Now you can access your variables from the same bash shell:

```
echo ${WORDS[0]} && echo ${WORDS[1]} && echo ${WORDS[2]}
```

Output:

```
test one
test two
test three
```

NOTE: this will work if you run the awk command from the shell. But if you want to save that command to your `script.sh` file, you need to call it like this: `. script.sh` (note the dot and space before name of the script).